# SVG Icons not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

In my web application i'm using SVG icons, main reason is dat i'm using than for multi-tenant design. I've tried a lot of options but in Internet Explorer almost every version, it doesn't work. It shows op like a o filled block.

Working code : Chrome / Mozilla / Safari

```
HTML:
<div class="svg_icon" id="icon_business"></div>

CSS:
#icon_business {
    -webkit-mask-image: url(/svg/business.svg);
}
.svg_icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    mask-size: contain;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position-x: center;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #00E3A7;
}
```

Could someone help me? What's the best way to handle this? And is there a way it works with IE 8 +

Comment: Actually I can't get it to work on Firefox (68.0.2) -> All white or on Edge (17.17134) -> All green. I made a fiddle because we can't access your svg image: [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f27wxacy/). Note that [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#Browser_compatibility) there is no support at all for Internet Explorer for `mask-image`

Comment: As mask-image is not supported with IE, as a work around are you available to use SVG star shape? If yes than you can refer this example. it is working with IE. Ref: https://textuploader.com/1r4n0

Answer (score 0):

You should use background image. Also SVGs are not supported in IE8 see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg).

This should work for everything above IE8:

```css
#icon_business {
  background-image: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12676/star.svg');
}
.svg_icon {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00E3A7;
}
```

To target IE8 you could put this in to the top of you HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

Then using the class ie8. Use fallback image (png/jpg/gif)

```css
.ie8 #icon_business {
  background-image: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12676/star.png');
}
```

Or use some javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much, going to try this!! Great

Comment: @Maradilly, Is there any progress on this issue? If you had find the solution than please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. If issue still persist than try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT , Excuse me, new to Stackoverflow. it didn't worked, this solution made the background green but the line icon didn't worked. I'm working on a solution but i'm using Gulp, so didn't find a solution. http://svgicons.sparkk.fr working on this one.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use SVG shape as I suggested you in my previous comment? As mask-image is not supported on IE, It can be the work around for the issue if you are using svg icons on a small scale in your app.